# Is there a HttpServer in the standard Java Packaging?

Tags: java

I've been browsing around quite a bit and I'm wondering if there's anything similar to the [HttpServer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/com/sun/net/httpserver/HttpServer.html) class in the `com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer` package. I really enjoy using this as it's simple to use and easy to handle get/post requests without much effort. I have quite a few applications that use it as of right now; However I've been told that I shouldn't be using com.sun packaging, because it's not supported, and there's probably something already implemented in the main packages.

Just trying to figure out if I'm missing it somewhere, or if it doesn't exist. I could always write my own implementation using Java.IO, but I'm quite lazy and it seems like a nice little class to have.

Comment: Nothing wrong with `com.sun.*`. Your informant is probably confused with the `sun.*` package.

Comment: No you're not missing it anywhere, the only issue with `com.sun.*` is if your application ever needs to be ported to a different JVM (like IBM's).

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like NanoHTTPD, a single class http server for Java.

https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd